# Can I guarantee that recv() will not block after select() reports that the socket is ready to read?

Tags: c, sockets, select, network-programming, posix

**Background**: I understand I can't just call `accept()` straight away after `select()` and assume it will work because there is a chance the client might have disconnected after `select()` returned, even if `select()` tells me the socket is ready for `accept()`. Rather, I need to set the socket to `O_NONBLOCK` and then test for `EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK` when I call `accept()` - see below.

**Question**: Do I need to do that same thing with `select()`/`recv()`? If `select()` tells me a socket is ready to read, can I call `recv()` and guarantee it will not block (or report `EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK` if it's a non-blocking socket)?

Here is the code I'm using for the `accept()` case:

```
    while(true) {
        fd_ready = select_for_read(listen_fds, 2);
        fd_client = accept(fd_ready, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &client_addr_len);
        if (fd_client == -1) {
            if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
                continue;
            } else {
                exit_with_error("Error accepting connection from client");
            }
        }
        break;
    }
```

(`select_for_read` takes an array of file descriptors and blocks until one is ready to read using `select()`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [select man page for Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html):

> Under Linux, select() may report a socket file descriptor as "ready
>   for reading", while nevertheless a subsequent read blocks.  This could
>   for example happen when data has arrived but upon examination
>   has wrong checksum and is discarded.  There may be other circumstances
>   in which a file descriptor is spuriously reported as ready.  Thus it
>   may be safer to use O_NONBLOCK on sockets that should not block.

Of course, that warning is in the bugs section, implying that the authors think that isn't an expected behavior -- but nevertheless, under Linux at least it is something that can happen.  Personally, I always set my sockets to be non-blocking; that way I don't have to worry about my program accidentally blocking anywhere other than where I intended it to block (i.e. inside select()).

Comment: Thanks. Is the snippet I posted above the right way to go about using non-blocking sockets (replacing `accept` with `recv`)?

Comment: Mostly -- in my programs I try to have only one select() call in the entire program; that select() call should be the only place the program ever blocks.  So I would use that select() call to get notifications about both ready-for-read/accept and ready-for-write (on sockets that I have data ready to write out to), and instead of just handling one socket after select() returns, I would iterate over all of my sockets calling FD_ISSET() for each one, to see which ones indicate that they are now ready for read and/or write.

Comment: It's not a bug. It's not expected behavior for some protocols, such as TCP. But it's expected for, for example, UDP, where datagrams are discardable.