# recvmsg returns EAGAIN after select reports file descriptor is ready

Tags: c++, linux, udp, posix

In my application on linux, I send and receive data using an UDP socket. Sending and receiving is done in two separate threads. Sending works fine.

In my receive function I get continously `EAGAIN` `Resource temporarily unavailable`. I do understand, that `recvmsg` may return `EAGAIN`, when I call it with the flag `MSG_DONTWAIT`. But as I first call `select` to check if anything is available for reading, I do not expect this result.

The function is called in a while-loop and  `select` returns continously faster than the timeout, so the message `recvmsg failed (11). Resource temporarily unavailable` is spamed to the console at a much higher rate than the timeout or any packages are received.

```cpp
// Passed values as comments
MySocket::ReceiveRet MySocket::Receive(
  void *data /* Pointer to std::array on stack*/,
  size_t max_len /* = 170 */,
  suseconds_t usTimeout /* = 1000*/
)
{
    static uint64_t rcvId = 0;
    MySocket::ReceiveRet ret;
    if (m_socket == -1)
    {
        ret.errorCode = -1001;
        return ret;
    }
    struct timeval delta;
    memset(&delta, 0, sizeof(delta));
    delta.tv_usec = usTimeout;

    fd_set readfs, errorfs;
    FD_ZERO(&readfs);
    FD_ZERO(&errorfs);
    FD_SET(m_socket, &readfs);
    //FD_SET(m_socket, &errorfs);

    // Check for new packages
    // See for '+1' reason https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539031/what-exactly-is-the-first-argument-of-select-function
    int retSelct = select(m_socket + 1, &readfs, 0, &errorfs, &delta);
    if (retSelct <= 0)
    {
        // Nothing received
        ret.errorCode = retSelct;
        return ret;
    }

    if(!FD_ISSET(m_socket, &readfs))
    {
        std::cerr << rcvId << " Not ready for read" << std::endl;
        ret.errorCode = -1002;
        return ret;
    }

    struct msghdr msg;
    struct iovec entry;
    struct sockaddr_in from_addr;
    union
    {
        char control[512];
        struct cmsghdr cm;
    } control;

    memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
    msg.msg_iov = &entry;
    msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
    entry.iov_base = data;
    entry.iov_len = max_len;
    msg.msg_name = (caddr_t)&from_addr;
    msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(from_addr);
    msg.msg_control = &control;
    msg.msg_controllen = sizeof(control);
    // Read the message and metadata
    int res = recvmsg(m_socket, &msg, MSG_DONTWAIT);
    if (res < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << rcvId << "recvmsg failed (" << errno << "). " << strerror(errno) << " FD_ISSET(m_socket, &readfs): " << FD_ISSET(m_socket, &readfs) << std::endl;
        ret.errorCode = res;
        return ret;
    }

[...]
```

I do suspect, that `select` detects data on another queue (e.g. write, error), but I thought I've not requested this.

I've found [Can I guarantee that recv() will not block after select() reports that the socket is ready to read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577888/can-i-guarantee-that-recv-will-not-block-after-select-reports-that-the-socke), which points out, that select may sometimes return false values, but in this case it looks like it is always wrong.

PS: I've tagged this as C, as the socker API is a C API and the C++ Part of the code should not be related to the problem.

---

Edit:
There are multiple queues in a socket (data, error, more??). Select will return, when any of these queues contains data for reading. So all queues needs to be checked. In my case I used this code to receive data and if this failes I try to receive an queued error.

```cpp
int res = recvmsg(m_socket, &msg, MSG_DONTWAIT);
if(res < 0 && errno == EAGAIN)
{
    res = recvmsg(m_socket, &msg, MSG_ERRQUEUE| MSG_DONTWAIT);
}

if (res < 0)
{
    std::cerr << "ProcessReceive recvmsg failed (" << errno << "). " << strerror(errno)
    << std::endl;
    return;
}

if((msg.msg_flags & MSG_ERRQUEUE) == MSG_ERRQUEUE)
{
    // Error was received
    [...]
} else {
    // Normal data was received
    [...]
}
```

Thanks to [pmacfarlane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19639413/pmacfarlane), who asked me in the comments to check the returned fdset of select, which made me realize that select does not distinguish between queues.

Comment: You code is not C only C++. Use the correct tags. Corrected

Comment: Why are you using the control message structure? It's seldom needed, and doesn't pertain to the actual payload (the actual data) of the message. You can set the pointer to `nullptr` and the length to `0`.

Comment: Also note that for UDP you need to specify a size *at least* as big as the actual datagram being received. If the sender sends 100 bytes, you can't read it in chunks of 50 bytes each. Always be generous with the received data size and buffer.

Comment: And why are you using `recvmsg` instead of the more common `recvfrom`? What are your requirements for this part of the code?

Comment: You don't seem to be checking which set the `select()` has set bits in.

Comment: @gulpr as pointed out at the end, the problem is related to the C API.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I need the information from the cmsg (in the `[...]` at the end), So `recvfrom` is not an option.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I do expect messages of half of my buffer size. Also I would expect a different error in this case (`MSG_TRUNC`)

Comment: Just as a side note: I personally consider [`poll`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) API much more comfortable to use; maybe you might want to try that one instead?

Comment: @pmacfarlane Added a check to the code. The bit for `readfs` is set after the return of select.
As I only set a single bit in `fd_set readfs` when calling `select`, this should not be requred, as select does only check a single descriptor for a single event.

Comment: I'd suggest running your code with `strace` and see if that gives a clue. And maybe add the relevant bit (from the `select()` to the `recvmsg()`) to the question.

Comment: If you read the documentation for what the last parameter to `select()` means, and how it works, the reason for the `EAGAIN` should become very, very obvious.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I suggest you refer to the `timeout` value. This is not the problem here, as I return the function if the return value of `select` is `<= 0`.

Comment: With your comment that say `Pointer to std::array on stack`, what does that mean *exactly*? Please try to create a [mre] to show us. Or at least how you actually call this function, and with what arguments, and include the definition and initialization of all used variables.

Comment: Because of "msg.msg_control = &control", it looks like that ancillary data is also expected. Socket is marked readable also when ancillary data is available.
Anyone know what recvmsg() will return, if there is only ancillary data available, and no UDP datagram? (Is that even possible?)

Comment: I found out, that `select` does not distinguish beteen data and errorqueue (`MSG_ERRQUEUE`). So it will return ready for read if either the normal 'data' queue has data, or the 'error' queue. But even if I receive the data and the errorqueue (calling `recvmsg` twice) the programms spins out EAGAIN after some time. Will investigate this further.

Comment: @SKi I would expect, that the return of `recvmsg` will be zero (no bytes received) and only the cmsg/ancillary headers are set. But even for error messages, I got the original send message back.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. I've added a paragraph to the question with my workaround. `select` does not distinguish between different queues, so all must be received/ cleared to prevent a future instant return of `select`. Would be interesting, if `select` can be tuned that way, that only one queue is checked for data.

Comment: If you're not interested in the error queue why are you selecting on it? Specify 0 instead of `&errorfs` to `select()`. NB The return of `recvmsg()` is only zero when the peer has closed the connection in TCP, or sent a zero-length datagram in UDP. Zero does not indicate 'no message'. -1 with `EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK` indicates that.

Comment: @user207421 `&errorfs` is zero (`FD_ZERO(&errorfs)`), and the readfs is set after the select call. `&errorfs` detects "exceptional conditions" (nice 'unmistakable' term for a documentation :D ).